# How to make a modification on master and put also on all branches

Tags: git, github

I have 2 branches created from the same master. When I update the master branch the other 2 branches also should be modified. How is this possible?

Comment: Rebase the branches on master.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can do this. Your best option would be to commit to one of your branches (or a master branch) and then either merge the commit into the others one by one or cherry-pick the commit into each of the other branches.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do without a manual merge or manual rebase.

Imagine you find a mechanism that forces an automatic rebase or an automatic merge on your other branches. Then you would cause merge conflicts for your poor developers pretty often, in the branches *they* are working on (i.e. this would be similar to having them run "git merge master" on their branches, except they would not be aware of it in the scenario you propose. They would just suddenly have those `<<<HEAD` markers in their files and wouldn't know where they come from). Git prevents you from doing this.

Adapt your workflow to either rebase branches on master or to merge master into the branches, or to resolve conflicts when they arise on merging the branches into master.